# SQL Server Running a Stored Proc from Another Database

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have been executing a stored procedure which exists on database1 from another stored procedure on database2. eg: exec [database1].Schema.SPname 'parameters'

But I am not sure if this is possible only if both database1 and database 2 are present on the same instance of sql server.
Any idea?
Thanks & Regards,
Sarin

Comment: i think you can call the store proc from different instance of sql server, by using linked server.

Comment: That's a great idea. So just wanted to know: I hope I can work on multiple databases and do all that I can as usually with a single database like using select, joins, triggers and unions, or tables and views?

Comment: Yes. as long as you define the name of link server before the database name you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the instance as `Linked Server`:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'InstanceName', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'

EXEC [InstanceName].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[Procedurename]

SELECT * FROM [InstanceName].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]
```

Comment: That's a great idea. So just wanted to know: I hope I can work on multiple databases and do all that I can as usually with a single database like using select, joins, triggers and unions, or tables and views?